# How can I make my number generator include max value? c#

Tags: c#, random

Im trying to make random number generator and want it to include max value in array of numbers, what i did was use math.abs and i dont know if i even achieved what i wanted... so here is my code:

```
using System;

namespace _7
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello this is random number generator!");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter min number:");
            int pirmas = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("enter max number:");
            int antras = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            antras = Math.Abs(antras + 1);
            Random generator = new Random();
            Console.WriteLine("Generated number is:");
            int end = generator.Next(pirmas, antras);
            Console.WriteLine(end);
            Console.ReadKey();    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If, by using Math.abs you are trying to prevent the user entering a value for antras that is less than pirmas, which would generate an ArgumentOutOfRange Exception, then using Math.abs isn't the way to do it as weirdev correctly points out below. Use a try..catch or loop the input until the user enters a correct value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Math.Abs()` call is unnecessary and makes the code not work as expected for negative max numbers. Otherwise, what you are doing should work exactly as expected. Just increment `antras` by one.

```
antras += 1;
```

EDIT:
As Haukinger suggested, it would probably be better to not modify the max value (`antras`) and instead *only* modify the call to `Random.Next()`.

```
int end = generator.Next(pirmas, antras + 1);
```

Comment: I'd prefer `int end = generator.Next(pirmas, antras+1);` because it keeps the +1 in the context of the next call.

Comment: You're right, that is a lot more readable. I'll update my answer.